# Proving Heap's Algorithm for Generating Permutations

Tags: algorithm, permutation, pseudocode, heaps-algorithm

I need to prove the correctness of Heap's algorithm for generating permutations. The pseudocode for it is as follows:

```
HeapPermute(n)
//Implements Heap’s algorithm for generating permutations
//Input: A positive integer n and a global array A[1..n]
//Output: All permutations of elements of A
if n = 1
   write A
else
   for i ←1 to n do
   HeapPermute(n − 1)
   if n is odd
      swap A[1] and A[n]
   else swap A[i] and A[n]
```

(taken from Introduction to the Design and Analysis of Algorithms by Levitin)

I know I need to use induction to prove its correctness, but I'm not sure exactly how to go about doing so. I've proved mathematical equations but never algorithms.

I was thinking the proof would look something like this...

```
1) For n = 1, heapPermute is obviously correct. {1} is printed. 
2) Assume heapPermute() outputs a set of n! permutations for a given n. Then 
??
```

I'm just not sure how to go about finishing the induction step. Am I even on the right track here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This paper from 1977 contains a nice proof: http://homepage.math.uiowa.edu/~goodman/22m150.dir/2007/Permutation%20Generation%20Methods.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. For n = 1, heapPermute is obviously correct. {1} is printed.
> 2. Assume heapPermute() outputs a set of n! permutations for a given n. Then
> 3. ??

Now, given the first two assumptions, show that `heapPermutate(n+1)` returns all the *(n+1)!* permutations.

Comment: @IGNIS By the way, I accidently reinvented the algorithm myself but couldn't prove it. Neither did Heap provide a proof in his 1963 paper. Did you proive it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that sounds like a good approach. Think about how to recursively define a set of all permutations, i.e. how can be permutations of `{1..n}` be expressed in terms of permutations of `{1.. n-1}`. For this, recall the inductive proof that there are `n!` permutations. How does the inductive step proceed there?

Answer (score 0):

A recursive approach is definitely the way to go. Given your first two steps, to prove that `heapPermutate(n+1)` returns all the $(n+1)!$ permutations, you may want to explain that each element is adjoined to each permutation of the rest of the elements.

If you would like to have a look at an explanation by example, [this blog post](http://ruslanledesma.com/2016/06/17/why-does-heap-work.html) provides one.